# C program when segfault stdout redirect not being captured in a text file

Tags: c, linux, cygwin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        printf("hello dude\n");
        //cause segfault
        *(int*)0 = 0;
        return 0;
}
gcc test.c -o test
./test &> out.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
./test > out.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
./test 1> out.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Open the text file and "hello dude" is never written.  If you comment out the line that causes the segfault then "hello dude" gets written to the file.  Some how the segfault is interrupting stdout.  Is there something that can be on the command line to capture the output? I tried both cygwin bash and linux bash shells.

Comment: Why did you cast that int pointer to 0  and attempt to de-reference it and assign 0 to it? It was pointing to memory that it does not own and rightly so it crashed with a segfault.

Comment: @t0mm13b that was the intention.

Comment: also, notice the redirection, it was not really directing to a file, look at the ampersand, you were running this as background job.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `newline` in `printf("hello dude\n");`? In MSVC it prints the message before crashing. Have you tried `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: To cause a segfault to solve another problem.  I have a larger program that is too big to post that is causing a segfault and I also have printf statements that are being outputted but I can't look at them because I can't redirect the output to a text file.  So I posted this smaller program and artificially caused a segfault to demonstrate that stdout is being redirected to the test file.

Comment: stdio is buffered, try `fflush(stdout)`. And forcing crashes will not give you something defined and deterministic

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`, before the crash.

Comment: Forcing this crash causes the same result.

Comment: fflush(stdout) works thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
fflush(stdout)
```

after the `printf` works